# WPF application work on windows 8 tablet?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I am new to WPF. Currently I am developing a personal(at home) application in WPF. I am using Visual Studio 2010. After releasing windows 8 tablet can I install my WPF application on it too? What about windows phone 8? Or I need to create these applications separately in appropriate platforms?

Also I am using window encoder 4 for video and audio capturing. Will it work on the above mentioned platorms?

FURTHER NOTES:
The program is written in C# and is a full screen application(Means no title bar or close/minimize/maximize buttons).

Any more details or suggestions will be great full.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After releasing windows 8 tablet can I install my WPF application on it too?

Haven't seen any information about it, but I don't see any technical reason that would be banned.

> What about windows phone 8?

You have make a new app with Silverlight for Windows Phone or XNA (a lot Silverlight stuff maps directly to WPF so won't be hard). This one apply for WP7 and WP7.5. There is no official info about WP8 on this subject.

> Also I am using window encoder 4 for video and audio capturing. Will it work on the above mentioned platorms?

What do you mean? Do you use an app?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am using window encoder dll files for capturing audio and video (Tutorial link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control).

Comment: It's hard too answer. .Net CF may be missing some types or this dll would use reflection which is not allowed. The best way to check it is to make a test app in WP7.